# Remove directory of a known file in CentOS 6

Tags: centos, php, rm

I have a database that returns a string. The string contains the location of a file. What I want to do is to remove the directory that contains that file using CentOS command. Is that possible? I know how to remove a file using :

```
rm -f myFile.txt
```

and remove a directory using :

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

and by the way i m using php to `shell_exec();`

Comment: You seem to know exactly what to do, what is your question? Edit to elaborate.

Comment: my question is i have a path like /etc/httpd/config/httpd.conf but i don't want to remove the file i want to remove the whole config directory using php

Comment: You want to keep the file but delete its path? `mv` it somewhere else before, then.

Comment: nop i want to delete both in one command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be using `php` to remove the filename from the location.

However, if you prefer a shell solution, I'd suggest using `dirname`.

```
$ dirname /path/to/directory/myfile.txt
/path/to/directory
```

Comment: thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for.